# SQL - How can I INSERT INTO Auto populated incremented field FROM another table

Tags: sql, insert, auto-increment, insert-into

I have a simple DB with 2 tables:

```
Table1.....ID|1st Lot No|No of Blocks|Part Number|Date|Lot Qty.

Table2.....ID|---------Lot No--------|Part Number|Date|Lot Qty.
```

What I'm trying to achieve is When the user inputs values in Table1, the data is pulled through to Table2, but I need the value in [Table2,Lot No] to auto increment Based on the Table1.No of blocks.

e.g. User inputs:

```
ID|1st Lot No|No of Blocks|Part Number|Date  |Lot Qty.
1 | 62204    |     6      |   TR456   |1/1/12|2.978KM
```

Then when Table1 Row_inserted, Table2 is auto updated to:

```
ID| Lot No|Part Number|Date   |Lot Qty
1 |62204  | TR456     |1/1/12 |2.978KM
2 |62205  | TR456     |1/1/12 |2.978KM
3 |62206  | TR456     |1/1/12 |2.978KM
4 |62207  | TR456     |1/1/12 |2.978KM
5 |62208  | TR456     |1/1/12 |2.978KM
6 |62209  | TR456     |1/1/12 |2.978KM
```

I am using aspmaker and putting the code in the server event:

```
' Row Inserted event
Sub Row_Inserted(rsold, rsnew)

End Sub
```

I have been trying to achieve this using `dims`, `insert into`, I've done numerous tutorials and I just can't get it to work. My sql knowledge is moderate. But I've been stuck on this for about 200hrs NO JOKE, I don't like giving up.

Please If anyone has the skills to show me the way, then I would greatly appreciate your help.

Comment: What database platform are you using?

Comment: You're storing the same data in different places which can lead to data consistency issues. I would recommend rethinking your strategy and using a `JOIN` on either `ID` or `[Lot No]` (depending on what your schema and business logic actually is, since they're both candidates for a [`FOREIGN KEY`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foreign_key)).

Comment: You should investigate triggers, in particulr, an insert trigger on table 1.

Comment: @swasheck - I'm with you, this design is making me uneasy.  I'm actually more concerned about whether the user can have repeats of `lot` numbers (ie, two different parts with the same starting `lot`, or subsequent ones with sizes that would overlap).  Especially if this is supposed to be used in _any_ sort of concurrent environment.